# Cognos save report output to file system based on end user action on report

Tags: cognos

I have a report that my system users can access to view & download however all downloads happen at the client. Is there a way within Cognos 11 to save report output to internal Cognos file system based on a end user action i.e. say a javascript link or button on report that triggers this file report output to cognos file system? Any help or pointers in this regards would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not from the Report Viewer.

Navigate to the report.
Click on the More button (3 dots) or right-click.
Run as
Run in background
Advanced
Delivery
Save report as an external file
Set the name, Location, and Conflict resolution
Done

If "Save report as an external file" is not available, the administrator has not allowed the user to save reports to the file system.  If you are the administrator, see [Saving report output files outside of IBM Cognos software](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cra.doc/t_localfileoutputlocation.html).